# VBA value that corresponds to C++'s MAKEWORD(2,2)?

Tags: c++, vba

stupid but quick question: How can I generate a value in VBA (e.g. of type Integer) whose bytes corresponds with what C++ would generate with a call to MAKEWORD(2,2) ?

```cpp
// c++:
MAKEWORD(2,2)
```

```vb
// vba
Dim value As Integer
value = ' what value corresponds to MAKEWORD(2,2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `value = 256 * b + a`

Comment: So MAKEWORD(2,2) = 256 * 2 + 2? Perfect - thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that my code do not make verifications for overflow or other problems that might occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build an `Integer` from two `Byte`:

```vb
Public Function MakeWord(Lo As Byte, Hi As Byte) As Integer
  MakeWord = Lo + Hi * 256& Or 32768 * (Hi > 127)
End Function
```